# show next fieldset by making a choice

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, show, fieldset

A quick question, for my frontend development class I had to make a form with multiple fieldsets. I made it and it was OK, but now the next assigment is to show the next field set by making a choice.

Ik wil mijn aanmelden:
                
                Voor een project

```
            <input id="Stage" type="radio"/>
            <label for="Stage">Als stagebedrijf</label>
```

Above you'll find my code where it has to happen. The user needs to make a choice, either "voor een project" or "als stagebedrijf". I know I have to do this with javascript so I made a file already. It can't use a onClick in the HTML file.

So my question is, how do i do such thing?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event handler using the ['addEventListener' method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

Here is a fiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle. net/bj0mba74/1/
```

(you have to remove the space in the link.

HTML:

```
<form>
     <input id="radio_1" name="my_radio" type="radio"/>
     <label for="radio_1">Radio 1</label>
     <input id="radio_2" name="my_radio" type="radio"/>
     <label for="radio_2">Radio 2</label>
  <fieldset>
      <input type="text" value="Fieldset 1" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
      <input type="text" value="Fieldset 2" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function enableFieldset1 () {
    /* Code to enable fieldset 1 goes here. */
    alert('Enable fieldset 1');
}

function enableFieldset2 () {
    /* Code to enable fieldset 2 goes here. */
    alert('Enable fieldset 2');
}

document.getElementById('radio_1').addEventListener('click', enableFieldset1);
document.getElementById('radio_2').addEventListener('click', enableFieldset2);
```